# Using glmer for logistic regression, how to verify response reference

Tags: r, logistic-regression, lme4

My question is quite simple, but I've been unable to find a clear answer in either R manuals or online searching.  Is there a good way to verify what your reference is for the response variable when doing a logistic regression with glmer?

I am getting results that consistently run the exact opposite of theory and I think my response variable must be reversed from my intention, but I have been unable to verify.

My response variable is coded in 0's and 1's.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simulate some data where you know the true effects ... `?simulate.merMod` makes this relatively easy.  In any case,

- the effects are interpreted in terms of their effect on the log-odds of a response of 1
- e.g., a slope of 0.5 implies that a 1-unit increase in the predictor variable increases the log-odds of observing a 1 rather than a 0 by 0.5.
- for questions of this sort, `glmer` inherits its framework from `glm`.  In particular, `?family` states:

> For the ‘binomial’ and ‘quasibinomial’ families the response can
>        be specified in one of three ways:
>
> ```
>    1. As a factor: ‘success’ is interpreted as the factor not
>       having the first level (and hence usually of having the
>       second level).
>
>    2. As a numerical vector with values between ‘0’ and ‘1’,
>       interpreted as the proportion of successful cases (with the
>       total number of cases given by the ‘weights’).
>
>    3. As a two-column integer matrix: the first column gives the
>       number of successes and the second the number of failures.
> ```

Your data are a (common) special case of #2 (the "proportion of successes" is either zero or 100% for each case, because there is only one case per observation; the weights vector is a vector of all ones by default).