# glmer reference outcome string

Tags: r, logistic-regression, lme4, mixed-models

I am running a multilevel logistic regression, using the function `glmer` from package `lme4` in R. My binomial outcome (or response-) variable is coded as `c` and `g`.

My question is: how can I know which level of the outcome variable is taken as the reference outcome?

It seems the default reference is the first alphabetically (so `c` in my case), is this true?

I am guessing this after using the `levels` and `relevel` functions:

```
levels(data$Outcome)  
# [1] "c" "g"

test <- relevel(data$Outcome, ref = "g")   
# levels(test)  
# [1] "g" "c"
```

This seems to say that `c` was the reference before, but this is rather circumstantial.

My homework:
I did not find the answer using `?glmer`, or the online pdf manual of `lme4`, or these related posts:

For the case of a 0/1 coded response:
[Using glmer for logistic regression, how to verify response reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24334286/using-glmer-for-logistic-regression-how-to-verify-response-reference)

Got the tip of using the 'recode' function from:
[Logistic regression - defining reference level in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23282048/logistic-regression-defining-reference-level-in-r?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your reference level's order. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772775/change-reference-group-using-glm-with-binomial-family) demonstrates how do so. In your case write it this way:

```
data$Outcome <- factor(data$Outcome, levels = c("g", "c"))
```

**Edit based upon OP's comment-** To answer your question: Yes, factor levels are alphabetical by default. This R-Blogger's [post](http://www.r-bloggers.com/reorder-factor-levels-2/) discusses it more.

Comment: Following your suggestion sucesfully reversed sign for all log-odds estimates (e.g. my intercept -1.19 became 1.19). I also realised that `g` is my rarest outcome, meaning that `c` was indeed coded as `0` (which I referred to as the default) and `g` as `1`.  In other words: the outcome that is first alphabetically is indeed the 'default';   the answer to my question is 'YES'.